# laravel edit phpunit.xml to change environment when testing

Tags: php, xml, laravel, phpunit

I'm making tests for an application in Laravel and I want to change the default config of the environment variable.
In Laravel documentation:

> When running unit tests, Laravel will automatically set the
>   configuration   environment to testing.
>       You are free to create other testing environment configurations as necessary.
>       The testing environment variables may be configured in the phpunit.xml file.

How can I change the environment from `phpunit.xml`?

Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
>
   <testsuites>
      <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
         <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
      </testsuite>
   </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: you can accept my answer for further readers if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `<php>` section with variables for testing environment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        …
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="…"/>
        <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="…"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value="…"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: i want to use my default .env.php on testing environment and not have to add .env.testing.php or edit phpunit.xml ! thx

Answer (score 1):

You can have PHPUnit load the .env file of your choice during setup. In TestCase ...

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

    Dotenv::load(__DIR__ . '/../', '.env.testing');

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    $this->baseUrl = env('APP_URL', $this->baseUrl);

    return $app;
}
```